# How to put a space between hyphen and next character unless it's a multi-word?

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I have a text that contains both `multi-words` and dialog-like phrases like `-hello` and  I want to separate hyphen from the word only if it's not part of the multi-word, meaning hyphen is not surrounded by two chars.

The word could appear anywhere in the sentence, not just the beginning. *Example:*

**input:**

```
multi-media
-hello -oh, hi
```

**desired output:**

```
multi-media
- hello - oh, hi
```

Can this be accomplished using `sed` or `awk`?

Comment: how do you define "a dialog"?

Comment: @umläute you know, like a dialog in a book. a line starting with a hyphen.

Comment: in my books, dialogs usually don't start with a hyphen...

Comment: @umläute my bad. didn't know how to explain it better. feel free to edit.

Comment: I also think this is a weird way to start a dialog. However, I have seen quotes ending in `- author`.

Comment: @umläute because they could be in a single line: -hi -hi there -how you doing etc, if there's any hyphen which is surrounded by two characters it should remain untouched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with `sed` as follows:

```
sed -E 's/(^|[^[:alnum:]])-/& /g' yourInputFile
```

The regex `(^|[^[:alnum:]])-` looks for `-` preceded by the beginning of a line (`^`) or something that isn't part of a word (`[^[:alnum:]]` = *not* a letter or number, for instance a space or a comma).

The replacement string `&␣` tells `sed` to add a space after the thing we matched (`&`).

Comment: can you explain the regex please?

Comment: hey can you tell me why `echo "-a a-a a-b" | sed -E '/(^|[^[:alnum:]])-/p'` is printing two lines of `-a a-a a-b` ? I'm expecting to be only getting `-a`

Comment: The default behavior of `sed` is to print every line. In addition to the default printing you also printed a second time manually using the `p` command. To disable the default printing use the `-n` option: `sed -n -E '...'`

Comment: Aha. But why is it also printing the rest? `echo "-a a-a a-b" | sed -n -E '/(^|[^[:alnum:]])-/p'` is outputting `-a a-a a-b` and I just want the `-a` part

Comment: `p` always prints the whole line. To print only the match it would be easier to just use grep. Since you are also interest in the word after `-` add `[[:alnum:]]` to the end: `grep -Eo '(^|[^[:alnum:]])-[[:alnum:]]*'`.

Answer (score 0):

Easy in Vim:

```
:%s/\(^\|\s\)-/\0 /g
```